# laravel how to create page restriction

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Please tell me how to restrict the page using laravel,
i have 3 users.
1. admin, 2. client, 3. partner
i want if admin is logged in then open only- admin.index page
and if client logged in then open only- client.index page

i used in **route.php** following code-

```
 Route::group(array('before' => 'role'), function(){
      Route::resource('admin','AdminController@index');
      Route::resource('client','clientController@index');
      Route::resource('partner','partnerController@index');
 });
```

using above code this if no any user login then it's coming properly,
and suppose if admin logged in, then page redirect to `AdminController` but,
if i hard coded (url) hit `clientController or partnerController` like `http://localhost/laravel-login/public/client` then client page is coming.
so please tell me how to avoid these
sorry for my english..
thanks

Comment: Probably you have to create diferent filters for each role, and add an entry route for each one.

Comment: @fmgonzalez : I like your suggestion. Can you answer it ? I have a very similar code as your suggestion. I had almost the same problem with Reena.

Comment: @evoque2015 I have two levels of permissions. I can grant access to route level, so one user can have several roles and each role has some granted routes. In each route I ask for permissions, and looks for the route. It's more flexible but more complex to maintain. On the other hand, you don't need to add nothing to your controllers and roles don't need to be hardcoded.

Comment: @fmgonzalez : I am stuck in this question and no one answer yet. :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236098/how-to-apply-multiple-filters-on-route-group-in-laravel-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use different route filters for each route and create individual filters, for example:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::resource('admin','AdminController@index');
    Route::resource('client','clientController@index');
    Route::resource('partner','partnerController@index');
});
```

In each controller create a `__construct` method and add filter like:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // In your AdminController
    $this->beforeFilter(function() {
        if(Auth::user()->role->name != 'admin') return redirect::to('/'); // home
    });
}
```

Same way declare other filters in other controllers:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // In your clientController
    $this->beforeFilter(function() {
        if(Auth::user()->role->name != 'client') return redirect::to('/'); // home
    });
}
```

And so on. Check more on Laravel website about [controller filtering](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters).

Comment: how to add role->name

Comment: Create `roles` table and `Role` model and attach roles with users using `return $this->hasOne('Role')` in `User::role` method. It's quite a big job to demonstrate everything, I gave you just the idea.

Comment: it's working,but suppose i am login as admin and i hit page in url like 'http://localhost/laravel-login/public/client' then url displying as 'http://localhost/laravel-login/public/client' but page is admin page. **it's not redirecting**

Comment: Then check in every `__construct()` method of your restricted controller, i.e. `if(Auth::user()->role->namne != 'desired_rule') return redirect::to('somepage');`

Comment: //dd(Auth::user()->type);
 $this->beforeFilter(function(){
 if(Auth::user()->type != 1) 
 return Redirect::to('/');
 });

Comment: if(Auth::user()->type != 1) then it's not redirecting to home page it showing admin page but url is `localhost/laravel-login/public/client`, so please help me

Comment: It's working.. actually it was my mistake i used for admin and client same controller. thanks a alot

Comment: @TheAlpha : Is there another way to get this done ? According to the comment, fmgonzalez suggested to  create diferent filters for each role, and add an entry route for each one. Any advice/suggestion on that ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to restrict controllers to make new middleware , where you can define rules before the request. example :

I have a admin controller only register users with admin role can access it .
to do so when you define the route include the middleware .

// namespace = indicate where my controller is (sub folder )
// middleware = indicate what restriction i want for my controller you can pass one middleware or array of midlewares

```
Route::group([ 'namespace' => 'Admin','middleware' => ['auth' , 'IsAdmin'] ], function()
{
  Route::resource('admin/posts', 'PostsController');


});
```

to create the middle ware and register it follow the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)

look this is my middleware after

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IsAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if($request->user()->is_admin == false ){
        return redirect('/');
      }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```